# Need some input on a batch file im working on

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off


:options
cls

echo Please select an operation:
echo.
echo 1. Mount TrueCrypt Volume
echo 2. Start TrueCrypt
echo 3. Dismount All TrueCrypt Volumes
echo 4. Exit
set /p option=" Option: "

:files
cls

echo Please choose a file:
echo.
echo 1. Tor
echo 2. Other_files
echo 3. Main Menu
set /p file=" File: "

if %option%==1 (

goto files
)
if %option%==2 (
TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe
echo Operation Complete.
pause
goto options
)
if %option%==3 (
TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /q /d
echo Operation Complete.
pause
goto options
)
if %option%==4 (
exit
)
else(
echo Invalid Input.
echo Please try again . . .
pause > nul
goto options
)

if %file%==1 (
TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /q background /e /m rm /v "Tor"
echo Operation Complete.
pause
goto files
)
if %file%==2 (
TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /q background /e /m rm /v "Other_files"
echo Operation Complete.
pause
goto files
)
if %file%==3(
goto options
)
else(
echo Invalid Input.
echo Please try again . . .
pause > nul
goto files
)
```

This is a batch file I typed up to call hidden and encrypted volumes made with TrueCrypt.
Now the Options "screen" works fine, each option does as it is suppose to. But the Files "screen" doesn't do anything it is suppose to, you select a file you want to open and it does nothing just sits there, it doesn't give an error or anything so that's where it stumps me.

I am relatively a noob when it comes to Batch but I do have other programming knowledge.
But I was hoping someone would be able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some problems with spacing, notably the `if %file%==3(` line.  There needs to be a space between the `3` and the `(`.  Without that space, you'll get `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`  The batch language doesn't lend itself to code golfing, and spacing or not spacing is important.

There's a glaring logic issue, in that you're going to visit `:files` whether a relevant `%option%` has been input or not.

There are also a couple of general batch scripting conventions that may help you in the long run if you get them under your fingers now.  Whenever you set a variable to a string, consider placing the `set "var=value"` pair in quotation marks.  Also, quote each side of the comparison operator in your `if` statements.  Such changes won't affect this script, but the habits will result in less troubleshooting in the future.

Anyway, here's your script, fixed:

```
@echo off

:options
cls
set option=
echo Please select an operation:
echo.
echo 1. Mount TrueCrypt Volume
echo 2. Start TrueCrypt
echo 3. Dismount All TrueCrypt Volumes
echo 4. Exit
set /p "option=Option: "

if "%option%"=="1" (
    goto files
) else if "%option%"=="2" (
    TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe
    echo Operation Complete.
    pause
    goto options
) else if "%option%"=="3" (
    TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /q /d
    echo Operation Complete.
    pause
    goto options
) else if "%option%"=="4" (
    exit /b
) else (
    echo Invalid Input.
    echo Please try again . . .
    pause > nul
    goto options
)

:files
cls
set file=
echo Please choose a file:
echo.
echo 1. Tor
echo 2. Other_files
echo 3. Main Menu
set /p "file=File: "

if "%file%"=="1" (
    TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /q background /e /m rm /v "Tor"
    echo Operation Complete.
    pause
    goto files
) else if "%file%"=="2" (
    TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /q background /e /m rm /v "Other_files"
    echo Operation Complete.
    pause
    goto files
) else if "%file%"=="3" (
    goto options
) else (
    echo Invalid Input.
    echo Please try again . . .
    pause > nul
    goto files
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly how i want it to now! :)

Comment: Good spot on the `==3(`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
:files
cls

echo Please choose a file:
echo.
echo 1. Tor
echo 2. Other_files
echo 3. Main Menu
set /p file=" File: "

if %option%==1 (
    goto files
)
```

So if the user enters Option 1, then the `IF` condition will send them to the `files` menu which is above. The user enters, for example File 2, but `%option%` is still 1. The `IF` statement statement then sends them back to `files`...

To fix this you should set another label (for example, `filesExecute`) and have the `IF` statement send the control there:

```
if %option%==1 (
    goto filesExecute
)
```

Now define your `filesExecute` label in the appropriate spot:

```
...

REM Add new label here.
:filesExecute

if %file%==1 (
TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /q background /e /m rm /v "Tor"
echo Operation Complete.
pause
goto files
)
if %file%==2 (
...
```

Comment: yeah know that i look at it there is one, thanks for pointing that out.